# Starting/Stopping applications in ArgoCD

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, argocd

How to Stop/Start application deployed in the ArgoCD?

I see only *Delete* or *Sync* or deploy/redeploy options. I got running server applications and I'd like to stop (shutdown) temporarily their functionality in the cluster. Or I'm missing something in the concept?

Do I need to implement some kind of custom interface for my server applications to make start/stop functionality possible and communicate with my apps directly?  (so it is out of ArgoCD responsibility - i.e. it is *not* like Linux service management system - I need to implement this by myself at application level)

Comment: Looks like your understanding is correct. Only I was able to find in `argocd` github project are: [Ability to suspend an argo application](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/3039) and [stop an Application but keep the application definition](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/6079) which leads to the only delete/sync and deploy/redeploy options left. Also as an option, you can raise a question in their Github project, it will have more chances to be answered.

Comment: Stopping an application in kubernetes is done by setting the replicas of a deployment to 0. 

Commit the deployment manifest to git for argo to apply the change and stop the application.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the replica count to 0 so no pod will be created, without having to update your application code or remove the application from argocd.

You need to edit the definition of your deployment, setting the `replicas` to `0` like so:

```
apiVersion: ...
kind: Deployment
spec:
  replicas: 0
  ...
```

This can be done in 2 ways:

- You can commit the changes in your config and sync argocd so they get applied,
- Or you can do this directly from the argocd UI:

  - First disable the auto-sync (`App Details` > `Summary` > `Disable auto-sync`) so your changes don't get overwritten
  - Then edit the desired manifest of your deployment directly in the UI
  - When you want to rollback this change and re-deploy your app, simply sync and you will get your old config back