# CI/CD ArgoCD - how can we schedule a nightly build with ArgoCD? So deploy a temporary set of Kubernetes resources

Tags: kubernetes, cicd, argocd

Each night we run a nightly build. A 'docker-compose' stack is deployed, a Test docker container runs the tests. Works fine.

We started migrating to Kubernetes with ArgoCD.

How can we deploy a **temporary** set of Kubernetes resources with ArgoCD? So on any change in a Git config file, ArgoCD will update a series of e.g. 20 Kubernetes resources in a running environment.

The **temporary nature** of the deployment is important because it reduces the cost of resources in a cloud (pay as you use) context.

Try 1: In [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68827006/starting-stopping-applications-in-argocd) is suggested to set the number of instances for deployable resources to 0. OK, that works fine for a limited set of resources. The use of Helm charts may help here.

Try 2: We can create dynamically an ArgoCD application so it will immediately start creating the set of Kubernetes resources in the runtime environment. After some time this ArgoCD application should be deleted. Possible, but is this a good way to go? Is this how companies run their nightly builds? There should be a better way.

Try 3: Can we work with pull requests? With tagging items?

I hope you can suggest a better solution! Many companies will face this same challenge.

Comment: Did you have a look to ApplicationSet generator with the PR generator? Each PR can generate a Application in ArgoCD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on [Gaël J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389127/ga%c3%abl-j)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77506478/ci-cd-argocd-how-can-we-schedule-a-nightly-build-with-argocd-so-deploy-a-temp#comment136646555_77506478), using the [ApplicationSet controller](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/applicationset/) with the PR [(Pull Request) generator](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/applicationset/Generators-Pull-Request/) in ArgoCD is a practical approach for managing temporary Kubernetes resources for nightly builds.

- As an extension of ArgoCD, `ApplicationSet` allows you to define a set of applications through templating. That enables the creation of multiple applications based on a template.
- The PR generator feature of ApplicationSet can automatically create an ArgoCD Application for each open pull request in a Git repository. That is particularly useful for testing changes in a PR in an isolated environment.

That means:

- A developer creates a pull request in the Git repository with the changes for the nightly build.
- The ApplicationSet controller detects the new PR and uses the PR generator to create a new Application in ArgoCD, representing the temporary resources required for the nightly build.
- ArgoCD deploys the resources defined in the PR, and the CI/CD pipeline executes tests on these deployed resources.
- In post-testing, the temporary resources can be removed by either:

  - merging or closing the PR, triggering ApplicationSet to delete the corresponding Application in ArgoCD.
  - or explicitly deleting the Application via a CI/CD pipeline step.

```bash
+------------------+    +--------------------+    +-----------------------+
| Developer creates|    | ApplicationSet     |    | ArgoCD Syncs and      |
| Pull Request in  |    | detects PR and     |    | deploys Kubernetes    |
| Git Repository   | -> | generates          | -> | resources based on PR |
| with changes     |    | ArgoCD Application |    |                       |
+------------------+    +--------------------+    +-----------------------+
                               ^                              |
                               |                              |
                               |                              v
               +---------------+----------------+    +-----------------------+
               | PR merged/closed, triggers     |    | Resources are cleaned |
               | ApplicationSet to delete       |    | up by ArgoCD after PR |
               | corresponding Application      |    | is merged/closed      |
               +-------------------------------+    +-----------------------+
```

That way, each PR gets its own set of resources, ensuring test isolation. The process of creating and deleting temporary resources is automated based on PR actions. That method scales well with multiple PRs and nightly builds.

But... you need to make sure your Kubernetes cluster has the capacity to handle multiple temporary environments created by PRs. And you would need to configure resource limits to prevent excessive resource consumption, as well as monitor the lifecycle of Applications to make sure the cleanup is done in time.

---

As an example, you can add in your project Git repository:

```bash
your-repo/
│
├── argo-cd/
│   ├── applicationset-nightly-builds.yaml    # ApplicationSet configuration
│   └── other-argo-configs.yaml
│
├── kubernetes/
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   ├── service.yaml
│   └── ...
│
└── ...
```

With `applicationset-nightly-builds.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: nightly-builds
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  generators:
    - pullRequest:
        github:
          owner: "<github-owner>"
          repository: "<github-repo>"
          api: "https://api.github.com/"
          tokenRef:
            secretRef: github-token
            key: token
        labels:
          - "nightly-build"
  template:
    metadata:
      name: '{{repo}}-pr-{{number}}'
    spec:
      project: default
      source:
        repoURL: 'https://github.com/<github-owner>/<github-repo>.git'
        targetRevision: '{{head.sha}}'
        path: 'kubernetes/nightly'
      destination:
        server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
        namespace: 'nightly-builds-pr-{{number}}'
      syncPolicy:
        automated: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use a [sync window](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync_windows/). Represented by periods where syncs will either be blocked or allowed. It is defined by a type, which can be allowed or denied, a schedule in cron format and a duration, along with one or more applications, namespaces and clusters.

- The current window can be inspected with the command: `argocd app get APP`. E.g.:

[image]

- Windows can be created using the CLI:

```
argocd proj windows add PROJECT \
    --kind allow \
    --schedule "0 22 * * *" \
    --duration 1h \
    --applications "*"
```